# Digging a well, hitting a rock

Tags: hole, well

I am digging a well with a hand-powered auger. I am 20 feet down and I am hitting a rock. How can I break up this rock so I can continue digging?

Comment: Easier to move over a few feet and start again, if it's really a rock you can neither bring up or go around. If you hit rock at about the same depth in the new hole, you may be facing something that'll need a rock drill, explosives, or both...

Comment: @keshlam I have drilled two holes, and I hit a rock on both holes at almost exactly the same depth. The holes are about 20 feet apart.

Comment: What does a hand-powered auger look like? Does it have really big reduction gears? I would think a gas powered auger would be less exhausting.

Comment: Hitting that barrier twice, at that separation, suggests to me that you're looking at something larger than "a rock" and getting through it without pro equipment may be a major challenge. But I'm far from an expert. Good luck...

Comment: What makes you think you can drill down and hit water where you are?

Comment: Sounds like bedrock. So you'll require a drill that can drill rock, which usually means hiring a well driller, but I suppose there are hand methods if you want to persist in that (ie, dropping a heavy pointy object down the hole and hauling it up and repeating until you've broken up enough rock to be worth scooping out.)

Comment: I, too, am curious as to how you made it 20' down with a hand-powered tool!

Comment: Light a stick of dynamite and drop it in there. Repeat until there is no more rock. Just kidding.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check with knowledgeable people about drilling in your area.  Perhaps you have dug into bedrock.  Or there is a [large monolith](http://img15.deviantart.net/ee6c/i/2008/079/a/a/the_monolith_by_planet_fall.jpg) buried there. :-)

- In the U.S., the USGS has [much data](http://ngmdb.usgs.gov/ngmdb/ngmdb_home.html) available for your perusal.
- Perhaps you have neighbors with wells?  Talk to them and see what their experience was.  Even if theirs were drilled 50+ years ago, well digging stories seem to survive the ages.
- Your municipality might have well digging advice and experience and can advise on best drilling practices.

Answer (score 2):

rig up a 20 foot masonry bit extension and perforate the outline of you hole on it. There is also a product that will shatter boulders by using a material that expands in the holes drilled. heres a link    [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00EUBR2RY?keywords=rock%20breaker&qid=1445003598&ref_=sr_1_12&sr=8-12](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EUBR2RY)

Answer (score 0):

Probably way too late but when I ran into rock I took the head off and smashed whatever I was hitting... seemed to work pretty well... Also if you are digging into bedrock you might try dropping a really heavy pipe down there to break it. Unless you live in an area with hard bedrock you could probably get away with this...